# Dropbox Install Pop-up on Windows 7 restart

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I turn off the Dropbox Install pop up that occurs every time I restart Windows 7? It is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't normally happen.

I would try uninstalling DropBox, reboot, and then try re-installing again with Admin privileges.

If you are talking about desktop notifications from DropBox that it has updated files, try clicking on the DropBox notification icon in the System Tray, select `Preferences`, and then "uncheck" `Show desktop notifications`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this Dropbox forum information:-

**[Growl, a pain in the A](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20370)**
**[How can I turn off the pop-up notifications?](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=41487)**